# Passing Information in Segue Using StoryBoards

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6

I have been dabbling with an iOS app for a little time and don't really get too much time to invest into it. I am now banging my head against a wall as I cannot figure out how to get this working or what I have not configured correctly...I am trying to get the bodytext that is referenced in the NewsTableViewController to load into the textView on the NewsView Controller. At present only the title updates and the textview just displays the lorum ipsum text.

My understanding is that because I can see the info in the NSLog and if i try to put news body text in the title of the pushed view it displays in the title - my thinking is that I have failed to define the view but as I say I just can't see it! Here's what I have anyway...

This is the table that loads the data to the first view from a xml file

```
//
//  NewsTableViewController.h
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"

@interface NewsTableViewController : UITableViewController
{
    IBOutlet UITableView *newsTable;
    CGSize cellSize;
    NSXMLParser *rssParser;
    NSMutableArray *stories;
    NSMutableDictionary *item;
    NSString *currentElement;
    NSMutableString *currentName, *currentTitle, *currentDated, *currentBodyText;
}

- (UITableViewCell *) getCellContentView:(NSString *)MyIdentifier;

@end
```

Implemntation of the the code

```
//
//  NewsTableViewController.m
//  

#import "NewsTableViewController.h"
#import "NewsViewController.h"

@interface NewsTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation NewsTableViewController


dispatch_queue_t myQueue;

-(void) showHUD{

    MBProgressHUD *HUD;

    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];

    //HUD.delegate = self;
    HUD.labelText = @"News Loading";
    HUD.detailsLabelText = @"please wait...";
    HUD.square = YES;
    HUD.dimBackground = YES;

    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(parserStart) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
    //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {[self parserStart]; });   

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    //NSLog(@"View Did Appear");


    myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx",NULL);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {[self showHUD]; });

}


- (void) parserStart {
    //Insert a small delay for testing purposes
    //[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];

    if ([stories count] == 0) {


        NSString *path = @"http://xxx.xxxxxxxxxxx.xxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx.xml";
        [self parseXMLFileAtURL:path];
        //[path release];
    }
    cellSize = CGSizeMake([newsTable bounds].size.width, 60);


    [self.tableView reloadData];


}


- (void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSString *)URL {

    if (stories) {
        //[stories release];
        stories = nil;
    }

    stories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //you must then convert the path to a proper NSURL or it won't work
    NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];

    // here, for some reason you have to use NSClassFromString when trying to alloc NSXMLParser, otherwise you will get an object not found error
    // this may be necessary only for the toolchain
    rssParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];

    // Set self as the delegate of the parser so that it will receive the parser delegate methods callbacks.
    [rssParser setDelegate:self];

    // Depending on the XML document you're parsing, you may want to enable these features of NSXMLParser.
    [rssParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
    [rssParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
    [rssParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];

    [rssParser parse];
}


- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
    //NSLog(@"found file and started parsing");
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError {
    NSString * errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unable to download the news feed from web site (Error code %i )", [parseError code]];
    //NSLog(@"error parsing XML: %@", errorString);

    UIAlertView * errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error loading content" message:errorString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    //NSLog(@"found this element: %@", elementName);

    //if (currentElement) {
        //[currentElement release]; 
        //currentElement = nil; 
    //}

    currentElement = [elementName copy];

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"article"]) {
        // clear out our story item caches...
        item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        currentName = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentTitle = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentDated = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentBodyText = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    //NSLog(@"found characters: %@", string);
    // save the characters for the current item...
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"article"]) {
        [currentName appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [currentTitle appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"dated"]) {
        [currentDated appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"bodytext"]) {
        [currentBodyText appendString:string];
    }
}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    //NSLog(@"ended element: %@", elementName);
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"article"]) {
        // save values to an item, then store that item into the array...
        [item setObject:currentName forKey:@"article"];
        [item setObject:currentTitle forKey:@"title"];
        [item setObject:currentDated forKey:@"dated"];
        [item setObject:currentBodyText forKey:@"bodytext"];

        [stories addObject:[item copy]];
        //NSLog(@"adding story: %@", currentName);
    }
}


- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;

}



#pragma mark Table view methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [stories count];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil)

        cell = [self getCellContentView:MyIdentifier];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    UILabel *lblTitle = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    UILabel *lblDate = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
    UILabel *lblBodyText = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:103];

    int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];

    //NSString *articleValue = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"article"];
    NSString *titleValue = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"];
    NSString *datedValue = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"dated"];
    NSString *bodytextValue = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"bodytext"];

    lblTitle.text = titleValue;
    lblDate.text = datedValue;
    lblBodyText.text = bodytextValue;

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"NewsSegue"]) {

        // note that "sender" will be the tableView cell that was selected
        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)sender;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

        NewsViewController *nvc = [segue destinationViewController];

        int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];

        nvc.title = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"];
        nvc.textView.text = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"bodytext"];
        //nvc.textView.text = [self getDataToPass:storyIndex.row];


        // hide the tabBar Controller
        nvc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;

        //NSLog(@"Article : %@", [[stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex] objectForKey: @"article"]);
        NSLog(@"Title : %@", [[stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"]);
        NSLog(@"Dated : %@", [[stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex] objectForKey: @"dated"]);
        NSLog(@"BodyText : %@", [[stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex] objectForKey: @"bodytext"]);    }
}

- (void)dealloc {
}

@end
```

And now the view I am pushing onto...

```
//
//  NewsViewController.h
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class NewsViewController;

@interface NewsViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UITextView* textView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView* textView;

@end
```

And then the the implementation file for this view.

```
//
//  NewsViewController.m
//

#import "NewsViewController.h"
#import "NewsTableViewController.h"

@interface NewsViewController ()

@end

@implementation NewsViewController

@synthesize textView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.textView = self.title;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

[image]

EDIT: From what I understand this part of the Segue is where I am sending the information from within the sending part of the code attached to the parser:

```
    nvc.title = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"];
    nvc.textView.text = [[stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex] objectForKey: @"bodytext"];
```

If I set the bodytext as the title the information displays and thus why I think there's something that isn't correct with the textview, it is this point that I am stuck?

Any help would be appreciated as I am really at the point I don't know what's going wrong!!! I'm actually hoping it's glaringly obvious what I have missed! Thanks for looking.

Comment: You have not told us what is not working. Also, you have posted too much information. Please delete some and clarify your question.

Comment: I've posted all of the information I felt relevant as I am not sure what is missing that is preventing the information from passing to the triggered segue. I will update the post as it is the bodytext I am trying to get to pass over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a bit confused what this line of code is attempting to accomplish:`self.textView = self.title;`

But regardless, I think your issue is that you are attempting to set the text for a view that does not exist yet. Try creating an `NSString` (say `textViewString`) in your News View Controller and set that in your `prepareForSegue` and then in your `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` do `self.textView.text = self.textViewString;`

Comment: Yes thank you :0) I have answered the post below - this helped!

Answer (score 1):

I added the following to my prepareforsegue

```
[nvc setTextFieldContentText:[[stories objectAtIndex:storyIndex] objectForKey: @"bodytext"]];
```

And then in the View did load in the receiving view

```
[textView setText:[self textFieldContentText]];
```

And obviously setting the property in the receiving view header file

```
@property NSString* textFieldContentText;
```

Thanks to all those that took the time to look and help.

Answer (score 0):

Need to set textView's text property. Try this:

```
self.textView.text = self.title;
```

Comment: This will merely replicate the title? I am trying to get the parsed bodytext into the textview.text area. Thanks for looking though.

Comment: Does it successfully replicate the title? If so, where are you passing the title text through?